# Comparison operator on javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble being able to use a comparison operator to determine if a valid array name is being passed to a function. The function is below:

```
const clear = (arrayName) => {
    console.log(arrayName);
    if (!arrayName) {
      return null;
    } else if (arrayName == !kicks || !snares || !hiHats || !rideCymbals) {
      return null;
    } else {
      arrayName.fill = false;
    }
}
```

As you can see the purpose of the function is to set the elements of an array to false and the valid arrayNames are kicks snares hiHats or rideCymbals.

Where I console.log arrayName I am getting the entries of the array passed in via arrayName and not the name of the array for the comparison operator.

How can I get the name of the array to be able to use it as a comparison operator? Or how should I be tackling this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is `arrayName` an array or a primitive?

Comment: arrayName is a array

Comment: what is `fill` doing/where do you get a property of a string (which is not possible)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the name as `string`, When you pass your array into the function, it is going to be referenced in the function via another variable.

There is no such operator to get the variable name. You can instead use a hash object which will contain the `name` of your variable based on a key.

Try something like this

```js
const validNames = ['kicks', 'snares', 'hiHats', 'rideCymbals'];

const kicks = [];

const map = new Map([[kicks, 'kicks']]);

const clear = (array, arrayName) => { 
    if (!arrayName || !validNames.includes(arrayName)) {
        console.log(arrayName);
        return null;
    } else {
        array.fill = false;
    }
};

console.log(clear(kicks, map.get(kicks)));
console.log(kicks.fill)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array name is 'kicks';

var kicks = [1,2,3,4,5];

Here kicks is a variable and just point to memory address. You can't take the name of the variable here. But you can do something like this.

var kicks = {
  arrayName:'kicks',
  kicks:[1,2,3,4,5]
}

And then pass kicks.arrayName to your function to validate.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line you have the problem with:

```
} else if (arrayName == !kicks || !snares || !hiHats || !rideCymbals) {
```

Assuming that `kicks`, `snares`, `hiHats` and `riceCymbals` are existing arrays, and that they are globals, you will need to check for them as strings:

```
} else if ((arrayName !== "kicks") && (arrayName !== "snares") && (arrayName !== "hiHats") && (arrayName !== "rideCymbals")) {
```

and instead of

```
arrayName.fill = false;
```

you will need

```
window[arrayName].fill = false;
```

Comment: Hi lajos wouldn’t using && mean it needs to satisfy all those conditions ? I’m trying to get it to be kicks OR snares etc so would it not be “kicks” || “snares” thanks :)

Comment: @user2058234 check the conditions themselves. We are checking whether arrayName is different from "kicks" and arrayName is different from "snares" etc. If arrayName is different from all meaningful names, then we return null.